# Loading content into tooltip via ajax

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

I am using [this](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/#getting-started) Plugin to load content into tooltip via ajax. It is pretty simple to understand and start using it.
This is my jsp page in which I want to load content dynamically into tool tip on hovering on a link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>


<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>

<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.hoverIntent.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- optional -->
<script src="jquery.cluetip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.basic').cluetip();
  });
  function web()
  {
      alert('asffdsr');
  }
</script>
</head>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Question name</th>
<th>Group ID</th>
<th>opt1(#votes)</th>
<th>opt2(#votes)</th>
<th>opt3(#votes)</th>
<th>opt4(#votes)</th>
<tr>

    <c:forEach var="questions" items="${questionslist}">

                <tr>
                    <td><a  class="basic" href="http://www.google.com" rel="http://www.google.com" ><c:out value="${questions.question}"/></a></td>
....
```

If you look into the above code, at the bottom you will find the `<a>` tag with `class = basic` and the page to be loaded into the tooltip via ajax is `http://www.google.com`
In the head you can see the script src and the javascript functions. I have imported the all the js files into the folder containing the jsp page.
But for some reason the tooltip is not appearing. What is wrong here and how to correct it? And also is there any way of checking if all the 3 js files jave been imported into the page?
The following structure describes where the css and the jsp files are present. The css and js fields are present inside the **web content** folder and the jsp files are present in 

**WEB CONTENT


      WEB-INF**

      **JSP FILES..**
**CLUETIP CSS AND JAVASCRIPTFILES..**

---

This is the screenshot. As you can see the **js** fields are **not** being loaded. But the css files are being retrieved.
[image]

---

**EDIT#1**
The page is loaded via ajax inside a div. So on clicking view page source, we cannot see the the source code of the stuff inside the div.

**EDIT#2**
The `jquery.js` file is not being imported even when using **CDN** i.e in the network tab of the developer tool, there is no call made for the the javascript file.  I have given the `script src` line in the head section.

Comment: Have you added `http://www.google.com` for stackoverflow only, or also in your test script? I can imagine all kinds of cross-origin / cross-domain issues that will prevent the tooltip to be loaded.

Comment: @Roonaan : To my test script also. Even if that was the problem at least an empty tooltip should be displayed, right?

Comment: Any errors in the coonsole window of your debugger (firebug, chrome debugger)?

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly : no errors

Comment: @Ashwin, you will get the same result as Ryan described if you change the anchor's URL on their demo site to google.com or any external site.

Comment: More info about grabbing external content here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837717/get-html-of-external-url-in-jquery

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly Sorry..in the network tab, only the GET request for css is fired. There is no request fired for the '.js' files. The js fies are also present in the same folder as the css files.

Comment: Right click on the page and hit "View Page Source"...check and see if the script tags are in the rendered source, not just in the jsp page.

Comment: @RyanLynch : see the edit#1.

Comment: See my edit. The issue is that you are trying to load script tags via ajax.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800585/loading-script-tags-via-ajax for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Based on the edits to the question here is what is going on.  When you load content on a page via Ajax, any script tags in that content will not be executed.  See this question: [Loading script tags via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800585/loading-script-tags-via-ajax) for more details.  Be sure to read all the answers, as the solution may be dependent on your particular scenario.

**Original Answer**

You're trying to do an ajax request from your site to another domain, google.com.  This is not allowed by browsers, its called a cross domain request.  According the the qtip error handler:

```
error: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    if ( options.ajaxCache && !caches[cacheKey] ) {
        caches[cacheKey] = {status: 'error', textStatus: textStatus, xhr: xhr};
    }

    if (isActive) {
        if (optionError) {
            optionError.call(link, xhr, textStatus, $cluetip, $cluetipInner);
        } else {
            $cluetipInner.html('<i>sorry, the contents could not be loaded</i>');
        }
    }
}
```

you should be getting the following: `<i>sorry, the contents could not be loaded</i>` loaded into your tooltip (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiftyp/bUy4s/)).  Check the error console, the most obvious answer is that you are getting a `404` error on one of your files, which should show up in the developer tools of whatever application you are using.  See what happens in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiftyp/bUy4s/1) where I replace 'cluetip' with a non existant javascript file.  The chrome developer console looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I am not getting the tool tip at all

Comment: the main problem is that  I am not getting the tooltip only. I tried loading a page in the same domain also. The tooltip itself is not being displayed.

Comment: Have you checked to se whether or not the cluetip script and css are being loaded correctly?

Comment: Sorry..in the network tab, only the GET request for css is fired. There is no request fired for the '.js' files. The js fies are also present in the same folder as the css files.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. As you said the script does not execute. So, instead of dynamically executing the scripts, I included the scripts in the parent page itself. Just curious to know, When you load content on a page via Ajax, why only scripts are not imported but css is imported?

Comment: I'm not really sure.  According to an answer to this question it's just a non-standard thing that all browsers do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203762/when-loading-an-html-page-via-ajax-will-script-tags-be-loaded

Comment: Can you help me out with a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122789/using-google-charts-api-and-displaying-content-via-ajax-in-cluetip ?