# I am trying to use jquery load, but that doesn't allow script tags when getting a certain piece of code, what can I do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using jquery load to load html inside a div, but they don't allow script tags to be parsed when selecting a certain id from that file. I need to allow script tags to be parsed without the whole page to be loaded, how can I accomplish this. This was my old code:

```
$('.link_inner').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var link = $(this).attr('href');
$('#content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
$("#content").load( link + " #inner_main_content", function(){
    $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
```

As you can see, that will not parse the script tags due to selecting parts of the external page, what is a way to allow script tags be selecting and only a certain div in the external web page

Comment: I've put the the script inside the div, but because I am getting page fragments, jquery load will not parse the script tags, hence why I need a work around.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800585/loading-script-tags-via-ajax or you could use https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an ajax request like the following

```
$('.link_inner').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            success: function(e){
               $('#content').html('e');
               $('#content').fadeIn('slow');  
            }
        });
    });
});
```