# Insert jquery into variable

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to load script tag via ajax, one of the way to do it is to append it with `.html` jquery function.
I tried this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var flexsliderThumg = "jQuery(document).ready(function($){/ \
                                $(window).load(function() { \
                                    $('#carousel').flexslider({ \
                                        animation: 'slide', \
                                        direction: 'vertical', \
                                        controlNav: false, \
                                        animationLoop: false, \
                                        slideshow: false, \
                                        itemWidth: 143, \
                                        itemMargin: 2, \
                                        asNavFor: '#slider' \
                                    }); \
                                    $('#slider').flexslider({ \
                                        animation: 'slide', \
                                        controlNav: false, \
                                        animationLoop: false, \
                                        slideshow: false, \
                                        sync: '#carousel' \
                                    }); \
                                }); \
                            });";

      $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        midClick: true,
        overflowY: "scroll",
        alignTop: false,
        callbacks: {
        ajaxContentAdded: function () {
            $(".avish").html("<script>" + flexsliderThumg + "</script>");
        }
    }
});
    });
});
```

But for some reason the script doesn't excute:
[image]

Comment: Removing the quotes to not make it a string should work.

Comment: why an earth are you appending javascript with javascript ?:

Comment: @madalinivascu I need to load script tag via Ajax and according this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800585/loading-script-tags-via-ajax What I did should work..

Comment: a don't see a byte of ajax in your code

Comment: A second issue will be that you are appending a script with `jQuery(document).ready(` after your dom is ready. So this function will never be executed because the site is already loaded.

Comment: @madalinivascu I shorten the code to make it more clear, I edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger the above libraries after ajax place your code in the success function

```
    $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax',
  midClick: true,
  overflowY: "scroll",
  alignTop: false,
  callbacks: {
    ajaxContentAdded: function() {
      $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        direction: 'vertical',
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 143,
        itemMargin: 2,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
      });
      $('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        sync: '#carousel'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I can swear I tried this yesterday and it didn't work, now it does.. thanks!

Comment: edit the code in the answer to the one in the js fiddle.. the 'success' is not unnecessary.

Comment: Yes but its more understandable for newbies in javascript like me.. thanks for your help, I solved it after two days of of researching..